# SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA fails if try to use Custom Auth Challenge Lambda Triggers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have a question with AWS Cognito:
Initially, the UserPool and the UserPool Client were configured by default to:

`authenticationFlowType: 'USER_SRP_AUTH'`

users were also allowed to use MFA

Right now we decided to switch to [Custom Auth Challenge Lambda Triggers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-challenge.html)

`authenticationFlowType:  'CUSTOM_AUTH'`

to add specific logic for authentication

and unfortunately faced with the fact that `SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA` falls off, the answer from AWS Cognito is now different
(instead of information about device comes next step for `CUSTOM_AUTH`) and Amplify throws an error:

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'NewDeviceMetadata')`

Is it even possible to use `SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA` with Custom authentication challenge Lambda triggers and if yes, how to do this correct?

**UPD**: I created [issue/bug report](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/9592) at Amplify repo with full description